# call webservice over HTTPs in android using ksoap2

Tags: android

Hi all i am working on web services in android using ksaop2 library, i have done with http but when try over https then i got exception

**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**
my wsdl file is asking username and password to open
Can you please help me how to call web service over ssl